# Multiple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\int \int \int (x^{4}+y^{4})dxdydz$

$D : x^{2}+y^{2}-1\leq z\leq 1$

$\int \int  (x^{2}+y^{2}) (2-(x^{2}+y^{2})) dxdy$

After that I stuck , could not find the boundries on x and y , I need help .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set
\begin{align}
  & x=r \cos \theta  \\ 
 & y=r \sin \theta  \\ 
\end{align}
Then
$$x^4+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2=r^4-\frac12 r^2\sin^2 2\theta$$
and
$$dxdy=\left| \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r ,\theta )} \right|dr\,d\theta={{r}\, dr\,d\theta  }$$
$$\int \int \int_{D} (x^4+y^4)dzdydx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r^2-1}^{1}r^3(r^2-0.5\sin^2 2\theta)dzdrd\theta$$

Comment: Thank you very much , but what change of variable did you use ?

Comment: I want to see a complete solution because this is my first multiple integral am solving .

Comment: I assume you meant dZ dr d(theta) not dX dr d(theta) ?

Comment: Thanks and sorry i posted wrong question

Comment: It was edited :)

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki In your last line, can you verify the exponents of the first integral?